# multi dropdown javascript works only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

EDITED
Hi guys, I'm completely new for javascript and I need your help to solve my problem.
I use this javascript for multi-level dropdown.Right now if I use it for two or more dropdowns,the second dropdown will follow the first dropdown sequence of selection.

The problem is, It every multi-level dropdown should be different.
Currently
Dropdown A:
1st level: first option
2nd level: first option content dropdown

Dropdown B:
1st level: second option
2nd level: first option option content dropdown

It should be,

Dropdown A:
1st level: first option
2nd level: first option content dropdown

Dropdown B:
1st level: second option
2nd level: second option content dropdown

Here's my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#multi-dropdown').bind('change', function() {
    var elements = $('div.container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
      elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
    }
  }).trigger('change');

  $('.second-level-select').bind('change', function() {
    var elements = $('div.second-level-container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
      elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
    }
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

You can find it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/aew2960d/

Comment: So what's the exact issue, now ?

Comment: Hi, sorry not to state the problem clearly, just updated the problem above.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple elements with duplicate IDs. In your case, both dropdowns have an ID of `multi-dropdown` (referring to the JSFiddle link). You just have to change the ID of the second dropdown and bind the appropriate event to it.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. but since I'm not very familiar with JS, what should i do with the script? maybe rather than call the id, i just need to make class?